How to measure power supplied by H-bridge inverter?
System description:
H-bridge network of IGBTs (inverter) is used to supply power to a parallel LC circuit connected through matching inductor. It is desired to measure and regulate the power supplied by the inverter. The expected range of resonant frequency is 10 to 100 kHz.
Query:
Most of the power metering ICs are for 50/60 Hz mains supply. For 10 to 100 kHz AC signals, how is the power to be measured?

Is this a homework assignment?

Measure the DC voltage and current supplied to the h-bridge. This measures switching and resistive losses as well, so you might want to compensate for that. Or use a current transformer.

@winny - No, this is not a homework assignment.

@Kartman - the power being supplied by the inverter is of interest. It is correct that DC link being fed to the h-bridge will indicate the power being supplied by inverter along with the switching losses present.
